# Attempting to select all img tags from php documents that do not feature alt

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, attributes

I have a modified version of a regex I have found on this site which covers most of my test cases:

```
(<img(?!\s*.*?\s*alt)[^>]*)(>)
```

([This](https://regex101.com/#pcre) may help understand Regex's better)

However, my solution catches -> and ?> before the end of the  tag.

Example of a current false positive:

```
<img src="<?php echo $value->Picture; ?>" height="150" alt="<?php echo $value->FullDisplayName; ?>" />
```

The code ends at -> after $value and thus does not see the alt later on

I have not figured out a way to exclude ?> and -> when searching for the end > (or />) in code. If anyone is good at Regex's and could help me out, please let me know an alternative solution.

Chosen answer

```
(<img(?:(?!alt)(.|\n))*(\/\s?|["']|\s)>)
```

Slightly modified to include both styles of quotes

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to format your message and include your code in the message (not in a link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
(<img(?:(?!alt).)*(\/\s?|"|\s)>)
```

(Providing all the image elements are self-closing - with or without slash)

If including newlines...

```
(<img(?:(?!alt)[\s\S])*(\/\s?|"|\s)>)
```

Comment: Not every image ends with a /> so this does not work. Also I am not sure this traverses multi-line properly

Comment: Ah. No, it doesn't. I'll have another look!

Comment: Updated - give that a go!

Comment: I've changed to 
    (<img(?:(?!alt)(.|\n))*(\/\s?|["']|\s)>) 
to allow for both styles of quotes and I will give that a shot later in the day with my current batch of test cases

Comment: Still acts a little strange for me if allowing newlines - might be easier to strip newlines first.

Comment: I miss some of my correct results without the newlines, although adding the newlines makes the selection excessive. The tradeoff is worth it to me. Thanks so much for the best answer.

Comment: What if the text `alt` is within the `<?php...?>` tags, though? `<img src="<?php echo $value->alternate; ?>" />` Should this match as the `<img...>` element itself does not contain `alt`? https://regex101.com/r/lI4oO9/1

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be optimized, but I wanted first to ensure proper functionality:

```
(<(?:(?:[^a<>?]+|a(?!lt=))*+<\?(?:[^>?]+|\?(?!>)|>)*+\?>)*+(?:[^?>a]+|a(?!lt=))*+>)
```

This [Regex101 demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/uB7yO4/1)
or [revision 2](https://regex101.com/r/mG5wW8/2) which has more test cases.

Throw in other test cases to be sure that other types of edge cases are being handled.

Alternately:

```
(<(?!\?)(?:[^\/a]+|a(?!lt=))*+\/>)
```

[Regex101 demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/mG5wW8/1)

Comment: Neither of these work and throw numerous of false positives. Thanks anyways though.